Choosing Thermistor for Electric Motors Monitoring using Arduino
I'm a Software Engineering student, with little hardware experience, and I'm planning to develop a sensor using Arduino, to monitor electric motors, including measurements of temperature, rotation, vibration, and shaft.
Initially, I am considering using a thermistor to measure temperature, attaching the sensor directly to the motor. During my research, I found thermistor models that are screwable, which led me to consider the possibility of attaching it to the motor using a nut. However, I am unsure if this is the best approach.
I would like recommendations for sensors that would be suitable for the project, preferably considering low cost and operation at 5V or 3.3V. Additionally, if anyone has tips or stories related to similar projects, they would be very welcome.
